# Java/JSP log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: java, jsp, log4j

I'm currently doing java/jsp project and I couldn't initialize log4j correctly. What I want is when Apache Tomcat server starts, servlet should run pointing to "init.jsp". Within "init.jsp" there is the location where "log4j.xml" path. I want initialize log4j when aparche tomcat starts. followings are what I have done.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Project01</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>init</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/init.jsp</jsp-file>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

</web-app>
```

**init.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,javax.naming.*,java.util.*" errorPage="" buffer="none" %>
<%@page import="com.company.util.LogUtil"%>
<%    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++");     
%>
<%!

public void jspInit( javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out2)throws java.io.IOException{
    System.out.println("+++++++++Init++++++++++++");
    String rPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");

    out2.println("rPath  "+rPath);
//location of log4j.xml file
    LogUtil.init(rPath + "/conf/log4j.xml");
    LogUtil.getEventLog().debug("Log initialized");

}
%>
<%
jspInit(out);
%>
```

The problem is when I start the server, Server doesn't start "init.jsp". So console says

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Login).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

But when I start "init.jsp" manually by right click on "init.jsp"page-> run as-> run on server, Then log4j works and logs are logging correctly.

Possible error point is "web.xml" dosen't call to "init.jsp" correctly. So "init.jsp" dosen't work when server starts. But I start "init.jsp" manually. All works fine.

Comment: Possible error point is "web.xml" dosen't call to "init.jsp" correctly. So "init.jsp" dosen't work when server starts. But I start "init.jsp" manually. All works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple. Use this code as init.jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java"
    import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,javax.naming.*,java.util.*" errorPage=""
    buffer="none"%>
<%@page import="com.mobios.util.LogUtil"%>

<%
out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(""));

%>

<%!
public void jspInit(){
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++Init+++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    String rPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    System.out.println("rPath "+rPath);
    LogUtil.init(rPath + "/conf/log4j.xml");
    LogUtil.getEventLog().debug("Service initialized,,,,,,,,,,,,,"); 

}
%>
```

Problem is at jspInit() function. Don't use parameters and remove out2.println (it use for print result in browser). And remove last function calling. This changes will make your init.jsp work